# Banned by my own cPanel?

Tags: banned

Banned by my own cPanel ?

Recently I wished to delete some members email addreess's for spamming. This seemd to go OK and when I

searched for the banned email address it was no longer found. But, I also tried to change the default

website that people are redirected to if they are from a banned ISP. It currently defaults to Yahoo.

I was presented with the error message below, and no change was made. Can anyone help ?

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the

request.

Comment: Have you checked the htaccess file to see if something has been written to it by cPanel that may affect accessing admin file.

Comment: I have checked the 10 htaccess files and they all contain this text
"Deny from all"
But only the htaccess in the system folder has Deny spelled with a upper case D. All the other ones are spelled with a lowercase d

Comment: Seems okay to me, must be something else. I only mentioned because when playing around with settings in cPanel it can sometimes add stuff to the htaccess file.

Comment: I have just checked the file permissions for for my htaccess files and they are all set to 644. Should I change them all to 755. I don't understand how I have been able to do anything at all with htaccess files set at 644. I thought that this level of access would have stopped me doing anything at all on the admin side ?

Comment: I have just heard back from my Hosting company about this and this was their reply ... 
Thank you for writing in.
Please note that the error you are seeing is due to the firewall settings enabled in the server. Please find the log below.
==
Remote File Injection attempt in ARGS (admin.php)
==
Since it is a shared server we cannot alter the firewall rules. We recommend you to proceed with your earlier settings. 
Feel free to get back to us for further assistance.

Is there a work around for this ?

Comment: Situation corrected. This is the explanation that I received from my Host - "The issue was with mod_security rules, currently we have white listed some ID's that cause the problem"